# Can I make one postbuildevent occur after another in a csproj?

Tags: c#, csproj, post-build-event

I'm trying to make one postbuildevent to go, and then after that finishes, then do the other postbuildevent, don't know if this is possible.

I really had no idea how to do this and I couldn't find any answers online, hope someone can help.

Comment: A Post Build Event can contain multiple commands.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but I want one to execute before the other

Comment: Can you [edit] your post with an example csproj file? I don't see why you can't have one Post Build Event with multiple commands.

Comment: The reason I can't have one is because they execute at the same time, I want one of the commands to execute before the other command.